# Tool for instant website user feedback

Tags: feedback, customer-support

What are tools that will enable users to quickly give feedback?

I imagine the user could always click on any element of the webpage (or do it without referring to an element) and just shoot a comment, with or without providing her/his email to get a response.

Something like http://critiquethesite.com/, but much less intrusive. I should also be able to integrate that to existing websites, and not use an external service.

Comment: Are you asking in the context of UX testing or general website tools?

Comment: @jcmeloni My context is general usage. Not necessarily for UX testers, but for plain Joes who want to complain or suggest improvements.

Comment: Why nothing external? My first thought was http://www.getsatisfaction/ or http://www.uservoice.com/ - since you asked for something not external these ones might not fit your requirements.

Comment: @user12999 I meant external in the sense that I would be using an external site to ux test my own. Uservoice looks almost perfect on first glance.

Comment: @user12999 Could you convert your recommendations to an answer, I think uservoice is just what I need.

Comment: I like this idea:  It should be something as simple as a little comment bubble which you can drag from an edge to the location of the problem; write a comment in - eg "this does not make sense !" ; and press send.  Anything that involves the minimum possible user effort is a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.getsatisfaction/ or http://www.uservoice.com/ might help.

There is plenty of reviews on the web. Since these products changed a lot over time, I'd suggest to look for reviews not older that 12 month.

Answer (score 2):

One great feedback system is used on [my local Newspapers web site](http://www.sydsvenskan.se/malmo/visar-hariga-armhalor-pa-mollan). They use four buttons where readers have the ability to press one of these buttons at the bottom.  The buttons represent a mood of the user after reading the article. The votes end up in a square representing user votes as percentage of the total area and a text saying how many percent of the users voted for this particular mood.

[image: Feedback image from sydsvenskan.se]

*Translation from Swedish in the above image*

- Green button: I get happy
- Red button: I get angry
- Yellow button: I am curious
- Cyan button: I don't care

Below that feedback system, there is an ordinary commentating system, supervised by a moderator. These kind of feedback is only selected to the articles that users are more likely to have an opinion on, as you will see if you look at the image of the [article](http://www.sydsvenskan.se/malmo/visar-hariga-armhalor-pa-mollan).

Comment: This looks more like a tool for polls and the visualization of the results?